# How to covert xml to xsd in oracle

Tags: xml, oracle11g, xsd

I have a query, which is generating the data stored in Oracle table into XML format. Now I want to convert the XML format into XSD. How I can go ahead with this requirement? As I am new to XML, any pointers to do this will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot "convert" XML to XSD. An XSD schema is a description of a class of documents (for example, purchase orders or travel itineraries). You can generate an XSD that describes one particular document, but there are many possible schemas that describe one document, and generating the schema involves making guesses about what might appear in other documents of the same kind.

You'll find tools that attempt to generate a schema from an instance document in many of the XML IDEs such as oXygen. It will never be perfect. But it depends what you are trying to achieve - which you haven't really explained. Why do you need the XSD?

Comment: Thanks for the explaination, We need to send some data in xml form to a system and that is the reason why they need the xsd of that xml too. As far as I know (based on yesterday's analysis) that very system will register on the basis of provided xsd and then import the data provided by xml.

Comment: What we want 

<xsd:schema 
 targetNamespace ="https://www.dbcde.com/sf/projects/flash_rwa_sandbox/mrrwa-fcl-contracts"   xmlns="https://www.dbcde.com/sf/projects/flash_rwa_sandbox/mrrwa-fcl-contracts"  
 xmlns:xsd="https://www.w3.ord/2001/XMLSchema" 
 xmlns:infatype="https://www.informatica.com/types/" elementFormDefauly ="unqualified" attributeFormDefault="unqualified"> 
 <xsd:complexType name="entity"> 
 <xsd:sequence> 
  <xsd:element name="report_date" typr="vsd:date" maxoccurs="1" minoccurs="1"></xsd:element>
 </xsd:sequence>
 </xsd:complexType>
</xsd:schema> do u hv a way to generate it?